# angular js definition issues on config declaration

Tags: angularjs

I want to know why my config function is not injected properly. this is my module injection code

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute'])
.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl)
.controller('common', common)
.config('configuration', configuration)
.factory('cprPostService', cprPostService);
```

this is my config declaration I get the following error

```
[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.13%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dfn%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520string%0A%20%20%20at%20yb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A354)%0A%20%20%20at%20Qa%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A447)%0A%20%20%20at%20jc%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A28%3A333)%0A%20%20%20at%20d%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A30%3A291)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%3A294)%0A%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A278)%0A%20%20%20at%20e%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%3A115)%0A%20%20%20at%20ac%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A230)%0A%20%20%20at%20c%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A429)%0A%20%20%20at%20%24b%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.13%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A133)
```

function configuration($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

```
 $routeProvider
   .when('/List', {
       templateUrl: './pages/templates/initialization.html',
       controller:'myCtrl'
   }) 
   .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/List'
      });
```

};

Comment: Have you included the angular-route.js in your script reference?

Comment: yes I have included it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the error line is

```
.config('configuration', configuration)
```

it has to be just,

```
.config(configuration)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a $inject array for the config fuction:

```
configuration.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
```

Comment: where should I inject it

Comment: I usually put it immediately ahead of the function declaration.